# Check if value is in mysql's table's column

Tags: php, mysql

How can I check if value is in mysql's table's column?

Right now I'm creating a login system. After the user registers my php file posts the value and makes it into a variable. I was wondering what code i can use to compare my value to those values in the table and to check whether or not there is a value identical to the value entered.

I tried this code.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='$username';";

$res = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query));
```

and then `if ($res >= 0);`

but then i get this error,

> Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/synameg1/public_html/giveaway/appfiles/register.php on line 23

so i was wondering if there is either a way to fix this error or do what i want to do in another method.

Thanks!

Comment: The error means the query you gave it was not valid. You can't count the number of rows in `false`, which is what `mysql_query` returns in that case. Find out why and fix that. `mysql_error()` contains the error message from MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error occurred in [$sql]: " . mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: I would not recommend die() with the mysql error on production systems. You wouldn't want the whole world to know what exactly went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Dan: I used your approach with 'zero' result.

```
<?php
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$user_nam = $current_user->user_login;
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'Private'; ////the user name
$db_pwd = 'Private';  /////the pasword

$database = 'Datapase name';/////////
$table = 'Table Name'; ///table name

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE 'Submitted Login' = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($user_nam) . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error occurred in [$sql]: " . mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo $user_nam . "<br />";
echo "count is $count";

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
?>
```

Private fields have comments.
It works, I can see $user_nam but the count is zero.
Here is a datebase peek so you can see the values.
http://you-get-real.com/images/database-peek.png

Thanks

Comment: hmm ... is this an expansion of the accepted answer or some further question? If the latter, please post it as a ... [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :-)